# Let AppleScript send email, then restart computer via shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, applescript

I'm working on converting my MBP into a media center, and one of the apps I have set up on it will run a script if the computer gets too hot. If this happened, it would trigger an AppleScript that would send me an email (telling me what happened) and then restart the computer.

The problem however is that the restart won't wait until Mail has sent the message. How can I remedy this?

```
tell application "Mail"
   set theNewMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"Media Center Alert", content:"Media Center has encountered a problem. It is now restarting. ", visible:false}
   tell theNewMessage
       make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:"myemail"}
       send
   end tell
end tell
tell application "Finder"
   do shell script "reboot now" password "mypass" with administrator privileges
end tell
```

Also, the reason why I am using a shell script to restart the computer is because I couldn't find a way to dismiss the "Do you want to save..." dialogs while using just restart.

Comment: If I were you, I would wrap the everything in the `tell application "Mail"` block in a nested `considering application responses` block. As for rebooting, try this: `do shell script "/sbin/shutdown -r now" with administrator privileges password "yourPass"`

Comment: Why would you wrap it in those? And that shell script looks like it just shuts down, not reboots?

Comment: The `considering` clause tells AppleScript to wait for Mail to finish doing whatever it needs to do. And that line will reboot your computer.

Comment: Alright, I did what you suggested, but it still seems to restart before the message has finished sending. I think I'll just put a delay in there.

Comment: instead of using `Mail.app`, you could use a shell script to actually *send* the mail. eg. [msmtp](http://www.tuaw.com/2010/05/04/msmtp-a-free-tool-to-send-email-from-terminal/) or `mail` (type `man mail`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check in loop properties 'id' of your message in sent mailbox and reboot if it there or reboot if mail can't sent for 15 minutes:

```
tell application "Mail"
    set my_id to id of theNewMessage

    set startDate to current date
    set rebootDate to (current date) + 15 * minutes
    rebootDate + 15 * minutes

    -- wait 15 minutes for Mail.app, then reboot if message cannot be sent
    repeat while startDate is not equal to rebootDate
        set last_msg to first message of sent mailbox
        set last_msg_id to id of last_msg

        if last_msg_id is equal to my_id then
            -- reboot
        end if
        delay 15
    end repeat
end tell
```

note: I haven't tested this code much, please test it by yourself if you like.

Comment: So there's no way to just check if it was completed then run the shell script? I want to keep this really simple and straightforward, and get rid of the try sending the email again. The email gets sent if the temperature of the computer overheats, so I'd like to restart is ASAP.

Comment: You can check sent mailbox for your message or you can check 'date sent' property of message.
I added 15 minutes loop for safety. Because if Mail.app can't send you message and you'll wait for it reboot never cause.

Answer (score 0):

dive's answer didn't work for me as there is no way to match an outgoing messages "id" with a mailbox messages "id" or "message id", are there is no "date sent" property in an outgoing mesage. However doing a count of the number of messages in the sent mailbox works:

```
tell application "Mail"

    set numOutgoingMessages to 1
    set secondsToWait to 10

    set preSentCount to count messages in sent mailbox
    set secondsPassed to 0

    repeat while secondsPassed is less than secondsToWait

        set curSentCount to count messages in sent mailbox

        if curSentCount is greater than or equal to preSentCount + numOutgoingMessages then
            set secondsPassed to secondsToWait + 1
        end if

        if secondsPassed is less than secondsToWait then
            delay 1
        end if

        set secondsPassed to secondsPassed + 1

    end repeat

end tell
```

and surely this should not be in the linux section?